# Schengen business visa for an Indian on OPT in the USA

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, business-travel

My office is planning to send me to the parent company in Germany for a 3-month business visit. I am currently working on OPT visa and my H1 will be filed this year (just stating in case this matters). My likely months of travel will be June-August.

So what is the process to apply for the Schengen visa? Will there be complications? I have read on the German mission's in the United States website that one has to be a US resident. Does that mean I have to be a permanent resident? Will I have a problem while returning from germany back to the USA?

If anyone was in the same situation I would like to know their answer!

Thanks.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this because it should really be asked in [expatriates.se]. Here are some things you should include when you repost a new question there: Do you have a valid EAD card? What is the duration, start and end dates of your OPT? Do you have an I-20 with a valid travel signature? Is the company sending you to Germany as an employee, or as furtherance to your OPT training?

Comment: I would also point out that this is going to be a fairly complicated question to answer. Are you interested in the answer to the Schengen part (going to Germany) or the returning to the US part? If you try to include both in one question, it may end up being considered too broad. There is nothing wrong with asking multiple questions, breaking your concerns down to easily structured chunks.

Comment: @CGCampbell Really only the part about returning to the US belongs on Expatriates. The part about applying for a short-term Schengen visa for a business trip belongs here.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the part of the question that is on topic:

> I have read on the german missions in the United states, they mention that one has to be a US resident. Does that mean I have to be a permanent resident?

No.  It just means that you must reside in the US, even if temporarily.  Look at the documents they require to prove legal residence, and you'll see that other documents aside from those available to permanent residents are acceptable.